# What's wrong with this Regular Expression for URL

Tags: regex

I am writing a regular expression which should match URL of this type

http(s)://a.b.c.domain.company.com(:8000)

protocol can be http and https and port is optional

I have written this

```
$reg = "^(http|https)(\://)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]){6,}(\:[0-9]*)?\/?"
$url1 = "http://uat.upm.goal.services.ps.com"
$url2 = "http://uat.upm.goal.services.ps.com:9000/"
$url3 = "http://uat.upm.goal.services.ps.com:9000?name=foo"
$flag1 = $url1 -Match $reg
$flag2 = $url2 -Match $reg
$flag3 = $url3 -Match $reg
echo $flag1
echo $flag2
echo $flag3
```

I desire that $url1 and $url2 match the regex... but $url3 should fail the match (becuase it comtains commands). I want the URL to end at either .com OR .com:8000 OR .com:8000/

I don't want anything after the (optional) port and /.

Comment: Why the `^` at the end?

Comment: I am trying to force the check that the URL ends either with .com or with .com:8000 or with .com:8000/ but you cannot say .com:8000/?cmd=foo

Comment: Why are you limiting to `{6}`?  I thought you wanted to match up through `.com`.  Also, I think you need to escape the forward slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `"^(http|https)(\://)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]){6,}(\:[0-9]*)?\/?"`

for urls without query part use this:
 `"^(http|https)(\://)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]){6,}(\:[0-9]*)?\/?$"`

`$` means the end of line / string

I removed the `^` at the end since it's a special char meaning the beginning of the line

I changed `{6}` to `{6,}` which mean that there has to be at least 6 chars from the group

I tested this in awk and it matches:

```
awk='/^(http|https)(\:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]){6,}(\:[0-9]*)?\/?$/'
echo "http://u.ucm.project.services.ps.com" | awk "$awk {print\$0}"
echo "https://z.ucm.project.services.ps.com:22400/" | awk "$awk {print\$0}"
echo "http://uat.upm.goal.services.ps.com:9000?name=foo" | awk "$awk {print\$0}"
```

as you wanted, only the first two match.

Comment: I tried your pattern. you see it allows the commands... but I don't want commands. for in the example below $url1 and $url2 should match but $url3 should not match `
$reg = "^(http|https)(\://)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]){6,}(\:[0-9]*)?\/?"
$url1 = "http://uat.upm.goal.services.ps.com"
$url2 = "http://uat.upm.goal.services.ps.com:9000/"
$url3 = "http://uat.upm.goal.services.ps.com:9000?name=foo"
$flag1 = $url1 -Match $reg
$flag2 = $url2 -Match $reg
$flag3 = $url3 -Match $reg
echo $flag1
echo $flag2
echo $flag3`

but all 3 urls are matching with your regex.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `+`  after the letter groups. So `([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]){6}` should probably be `([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+){6}`, so that at least one character and possibly more are there.

Also, the `{6}` doesn't do what you expect (match domain with 6 dots) because of the way you wrote it. Either remove it, and allow any number of dot-seperated domain parts or change it to something like:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.){6}
```

Comment: but I have /? this means the / in the end is optional.

This + you mention would make it 1 or many... but I want specific 6 occurrences.

Comment: The `^` is used here as a delimiter for the pattern.

Comment: Yeah just figured that. Also my answer had another mistake. Updated.

Comment: Since there's no dot after `com`, you should probably change this to `([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.){5}(com|org|net)` or something similar.